# soapUI: how to add Thumbprint as SecurityTokenReference to wss SIGNATURE entry

Tags: soap, soapui, signature, ws-security, rsa-key-fingerprint

I have a question regarding soapUI:
I'm trying to add a ws-security header to my soap-requests containing a signature. To do that I used the soapUI-dialog "WS-Security Configurations" in the project preferences. It works as expected, but my server application requires a Thumbprint-SHA1-Id as the KeyInfo//SecurityTokenReference Element.
I found out that soapUI provides this option in the WSS Entry "Encryption" but not for "Signature". So my question is: How can I use the Key Identifier Type "Thumbprint SHA1 Identifier" for the Signature Element?
I thought about replacing the key identifier created by soapUI via a groovy script. But this script would have to be executed after the creation of the security header and before the sending of the soap-request, and I'm not sure, how to achieve that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key Identifier Type "Thumbprint SHA1 Identifier" for the Signature is added in SoapUI 5.0.0 that is release tomorrow (2014-04-09). It is also included in a maintenance release of 4.6.4 that can be downloaded at http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/soapui-nightly-builds.html.